# How to generate OAuth 2 Client Id and Secret in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

How can I generate client id and client secret for user based authorization.
I am reading this [link](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2) to authorize an user. But I have no idea on generating these keys and want to authorize many users based on these keys in ruby. Any starting guidance is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is generally used to authenticate users for your site by having them log into an external service (i.e. Facebook or Google). The OAuth keys are generally generated by the outside service. Rails has some solid user authentication gems such as [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) that include protocols for common OAuth providers.

Answer (score 0):

You would get it from the Oauth provider you are using. For Google for instance you would create a new project on [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis) or use and existing project from there. Then you would go to api's and services. Then you would set up credentials and your Oauth consent screen.